# iPhone 8 keeps restarting - during / after upgrade

Tags: iphone, restart

I have an iPhone 8 that keeps restarting all the time. What I suspect happened, the phone run out of space while an upgrade was performed and it is stuck in some kind upgrade/post upgrade step.

Is there anything I can do to recover the data, I really only care about the photos.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you have iCloud turned on for all your applications and data prior to attempting the upgrade?

Comment: nope, iCloud was not enabled

Comment: Did you have an offsite or online backup of your data somewhere?

Comment: Does it reboot randomly or is it stuck in a reboot loop? Will advise further after this. If random, make backup ASAP. If reboot loop, need to figure out whether software or hardware problem. My iPhone 8 died last year after going into an endless reboot loop (Hardware issue).

Comment: I don't have any reasonably recent backup, unfortunately. Phone is in restart loop. It initiated iOS update, and stuck in the process... as mentioned earlier, I believe it was not enough storage available on the device.